# Create maven uberjar without including an internal pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, uberjar

I have a maven build setup but it has been requested that I make one change to the uberjar and that is to not include the pom file, because it messes up my clients subsequent build that uses my uberjar as a dependancy. I know this is not the way to do this but my client cannot access my central repo because of security issues. So the uberjar was settled on as a deployment method. Now the question is this: Is there a way to not include the pom file in the creation of a jar via maven?

Thanks,

Blair

Comment: Your client can use `mvn install:install-file` to install your `uber jar` to their `local repository` (At their harddisk). Please see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the maven-assembly-plugin to build your uberjar and using an assembly descriptor. What you want to do is instruct the assembly plugin (via the assembly descriptor) to exclude any files named "pom.xml". For example:

```
<assembly>
<id>bin</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>target/classes</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/pom.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </unpackOptions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

The key here is the "unpackOptions" section and the exclusion contained therein.

Hope that helps, if so please remember to mark my answer as correct so I get the reputation points.

Comment: Actually I was using the maven-shade plugin but this looks like a possible alternative. I will see if this works and if so will mark yours as the answer. Thanks.